# illegal number 'SPEED' firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm trying to import data into my firestore but I'm getting this weird error I can't seem to debug.

firebase code looks something like:

```
const db = admin.firestore();
const batch = db.batch();

data.forEach(item => {
    const ref = db.collection('data').doc(item.id);
    const {id, ...newItem} = item;
    batch.set(ref, newItem);
});

return batch.commit();
```

**callstack**

`Error: illegal number 'SPEED' (/node_modules/google-proto-files/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto, line 52)
    at illegal (/node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/protobufjs/src/parse.js:94:16)
    at parseNumber (/node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/protobufjs/src/parse.js:174:15)
    at readValue (/node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/protobufjs/src/parse.js:125:20)
    at parseOptionValue (/node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/protobufjs/src/parse.js:573:37)
    at parseOption (/node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/protobufjs/src/parse.js:551:9)
    at parse (/node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/protobufjs/src/parse.js:721:17)
    at process (/node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/protobufjs/src/root.js:107:30)`

Comment: What does your firestore and example data look like? Is `SPEED` valid data?

Comment: it has nothing to do with the data, I'm testing with objects like data = [{name: 'test', id: '1'}] and I'm still getting the same error. My best guess is that is a library issue

Comment: Your example is incomplete.  What is the `data` variable?

Comment: I had this same issue (also using firestore), its part of the loading not being able to find your google cloud config.  This exception (and the exceptions that follow it) didn't mess up the execution, they're caught and execution continues normally.  I found that once I removed the catch all exceptions from my debugger I stopped seeing all the noise and I was able to attach and then do the functions call command to start the debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @chris said on his comment, this error happens if you set up your debugger to caught all exceptions which was my mistake.

To resolve the issue just remove the debugger option to catch all exceptions.